# Manipulate a list representing Bach's Prelude in C

Tags: list-manipulation, sound

Bach's *Prelude in C* is repetitious in an easily modelable manner:  Each of the first 32 bars is structured so that, if given the first 5 notes, you can construct the entire 16 note bar by appending notes 3 - 5, then doubling the resulting 8 notes. So, given C D A D F, we generate CDADFADF CDADFADF. The attached code does the job, but seems ugly by having what appear to be excessive (and repetitive!)  references to  what I've called bwv846 (the notes from which the entire melody is generated).

```
bwv846 =
  {{"C", "E", "G", "C5", "E5"}, {"C", "D", "A", "D5", "F5"},
   {"B3", "D", "G", "D5", "F5"}, {"C", "E", "G", "C5", "E5"},
   {"C", "E", "A", "E5", "A5"}, {"C", "D", "F♯", "A", "D5"},
   {"B3", "D", "G", "D5", "G5"}, {"B3", "C", "E", "G", "C5"},
   {"A3", "C", "E", "G", "C5"}, {"D3", "A3", "D", "F♯", "C5"}, 
   {"G3", "B3", "D", "G", "B"}, {"G3", "B♭3", "E", "G", "C♯5"},
   {"F3", "A3", "D", "A", "D5"}, {"F3", "A♭3", "D", "F", "B"},
   {"E3", "G3", "C", "G", "C5"}, {"E3", "F3", "A3", "C", "F"},
   {"D3", "F3", "A3", "C", "F"}, {"G1", "D3", "G3", "B3", "F"},
   {"C3", "E3", "G3", "C", "E"}, {"C3", "G3", "B♭3", "C", "E"},
   {"F2", "F3", "A3", "C", "E"}, {"F♯2", "C3", "A3", "C", "E♭"},
   {"A♭2", "F3", "B3", "C", "D"}, {"G2", "F3", "G3", "B3", "D"},
   {"G2", "E3", "G3", "C", "E"}, {"G2", "D3", "G3", "C", "F"},
   {"G2", "D3", "G3", "B3", "F"}, {"G2", "E♭3", "A3", "C", "F♯"}, 
   {"G2", "E3", "G3", "C", "G"}, {"G2", "D3", "G3", "C", "F"},
   {"G2", "D3", "G3", "B3", "F"}, {"C1", "C2", "G3", "B♭3", "E"}}; 

finale =
  {"C1", "C2", "F3", "A3", "C", "F", "C", "A3", "C", "A3", "F3", "A3",
   "F3", "D3", "C1", "B1", "G", "B", "D5", "F5", "D5", "B", "D5", "B", 
   "G","B", "D", "F", "E", "D", {"C1", "C2", "E", "G", "C5"}};

tblBWV846 = 
  Flatten[
    Table[
      Join[
        Table[
          Join[bwv846[[i]], Take[bwv846[[i]], -3]], {i, Length[bwv846]}][[j]],
        Table[
          Join[bwv846[[i]], Take[bwv846[[i]], -3]], {i, Length[bwv846]}][[j]]], 
      {j, Length[bwv846]}]];   

EmitSound[
 Sound[    
  SoundNote[#, 0.25, "Piano"] & /@  Join[tblBWV846, finale]   ]]
```

So this is a question involving elementary list manipulation; it is not a music question.

Comment: Try this: `construct16Bar = Flatten[{#, #}] &@{#, Take[#, -3]} &;
tblBWV846 = (construct16Bar /@ bwv846) // Flatten;`

Comment: Thanks, @Anjan Kumar.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Very nice.  Is there a function to stop emitting sound?

Comment: @Quantum, remove the `EmitSound[]` part so that you get a player that can be paused.

Comment: @Christopher Lamb Nice idea +1. I know this piece of music very well, and that is why I stumbled over a missing tone in your list. I fact you must enter a "B" in position 24 (between "D5" and "G") of finale. Also I was slightly surprised about the hard final accord, maybe you can reduce speed and volume towards the end. So, despite your announcement it was partly a music question ;-)

Comment: @Christopher Lamb Just a hint: you can save typing time if you have the midi file available (see e.g. http://www.bachcentral.com/midiindexcomplete.html). This is a list of elements if the type SoundNote["G4", {0.407095, 0.609797}, "Piano", SoundVolume -> 0.439216]. You can Import[] the mid-file into Mathematica and then extract the necessary information.

Comment: @Christopher Lamb You might also be interested in the structural description of the piece in text book style. This is in German, the native language of Bach: http://www.lehrklaenge.de/PHP/Werkanalyse/AnalysePraeludiumBWV846.php

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze    Much obliged for noting my missing "B", and for the resources you supplied, the German one of which I'll pursue (to my limited ability).  I've also had fun with bwv564, which is delightful on MMA's midi harp.  (Speaking of changing instruments, I recall an organist named Anthony Newman saying approx. 40 years ago that he'd have no objection were Bach to be played on a tuned bathtub.)  Thanks much!

Comment: @Christopher Lamb Glad you like it. I have tried to play midi files from the ressource I gave in my last comment: unfortunately, the result is terrible. Speed variations and missing notes ... Hence I think it would be better to rework the files to get files of the type you have used.

Comment: @Christopher Lamb Glad you like it. I am busy trying to play midi files from the ressource I gave in my last comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thee is no reason not to do it with `Table`; the computation can be reduced to

```
tblBWV846 =
  Flatten[
    Table[
      ConstantArray[{bwv846[[i]], Take[bwv846[[i]], -3]}, 2], 
      {i, Length[bwv846]}]];
```

Beautiful music. Thanks for posting this question.

#### Update

The code golf version

```
mainBWV846 = (ConstantArray[{#, #[[-3 ;;]]}, 2] & /@ bwv846) // Flatten;
```

Comment: A slightly compact version: `tblBWV846 = Flatten[Table[PadRight[{}, 16, Join[l, Drop[l, 2]]], {l, bwv846}]];`. Personally, I like the violin: `EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[#, 0.25, "Violin"] & /@ Join[tblBWV846, finale]]]`

Comment: @J.M. I tried piano, violin, harpsichord and organ. The organ version sounds best to me.

Comment: To make it sound more human, you might for example define `randomRubato[] := RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[0.025]]`, and use `Sound[SoundNote[#, 0.25 + randomRubato[], "Piano"] & /@ 
  Join[tblBWV846, finale]]` instead.

Comment: Admittedly at risk of violating the "Thanks/Me too" taboo, I've gotta thank you for the education.  I value it (from J.M., bill s, Anjan Kumar, m_goldberg, and ulvi).

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect application of a user-defined function:

```
chorale[x_] := {x, x[[3 ;; 5]], x, x[[3 ;; 5]]} // Flatten;
```

Then you can form the complete piece by mapping the function over the data bwv846:

```
chorale[#] & /@ bwv846
```

though you'll have to add the finale on separately.